# Generalized Method of Moments

Tags: references, generalized-moments

I was looking for a book that could explain me well the Generalized Method of Moments, its mathematical nuances, and even have a look to the empirical side, maybe with some guided exercises with Stata or another software package. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the choice of Hayashi. Additionally, you will find more detail (not on Stata, though) in [Generalized Method of Moments, Alastair R. Hall](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780198775218.do).

Answer (score 1):

[Econometrics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/6946.html) by Fumio Hayashi is probably the book you are looking for. It treats a range of estimation techniques, such as OLS, IV etc., as special cases of GMM. A lot of the chapters include empirical applications of the methods used.

It does give data sets for the empirical exercises but does not cover any specific software package.